# Find the limit of the recursive sequence ${a_n}$ defined by $a_0 := 0$ and $a_n := a_{n-1}^2 + (4/25)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the limit of the recursive sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by $a_0 := 0$ and $a_n := a_{n-1}^2 + (4/25)$.

Assuming the limit exists, it is easy to see that the sequence approaches 1/5 or 4/5. I am not sure how to show that the limit exists though.

Comment: This is entirely standard: the function $f(x)=x^2+\frac4{25}$ is increasing and such that $f(x)>x$ for $x$ in $[0,\frac15)$, with $f(\frac15)=\frac15$. This, and the fact that $a_0$ is in $[0,\frac15]$, suffices to imply that $(a_n)$ increases to $\frac15$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

The possible limits are $0.2$ and $0.8$ because the limit must solve the equation $x^2+\frac{4}{25}=x$ . Now show that the sequence is striclty increasing and bounded from above by $0.2$ by induction to show that the limit is $0.2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Prove the sequence is bounded and increasing. For this it is enough to note that if $a_{n-1} \in [0, \frac15]$, then
$$a_n = a_{n-1}^2 + \frac4{25} \leqslant \frac1{25} + \frac4{25} = \frac15$$

and
$$a_n = a_{n-1}^2 + \frac4{25} \geqslant 5(a_{n-1}^2)^{1/5}\left(\frac1{25}\right)^{4/5} = (5)^{-3/5}a_{n-1}^{2/5} \geqslant a_{n-1} \geqslant 0$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$a_1=2/5>1/5$$

by induction , prove that
$$a_{n+1}>a_n $$

and
$$a_n< 4/5$$